# Make product data tabs collapsed by default

Tags: magento2, template, jquery, product-view, accordion

I want all product data tabs on the product details page to be collapsed by default.
I edited this line in
 `app/design/frontend/<Namespace>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml`

```
<div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active", "active":"false"}}'>
```

This does what I want but with the following problem:

On page load the reviews tab is expaned, for a short time.
It then gets closed during page load and after the page has rendered all tabs are collapsed.

This creates a visual effect that I don't like.

How can I make all tabs be collapsed from the start instead.

Here's the rest of the template, should be Magento default though apart from my change:

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details $block */
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')) :?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active", "active":"false"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name) :?>
                <?php
                $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                if (!trim($html)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="trigger"
                       href="#<?= $block->escapeUrl($alias) ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content"
                     aria-labelledby="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>" data-role="content">
                    <div class="product-data-tab-wrapper">
                        <div class="product-data-tab-content"><?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "productDetails": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the page load You can add below less in your custome theme

```
.product {
    &.info {
        &.detailed {
            .product.data.items {
                > .item.content {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```